# jqgrid resizable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Does anybody know how to make a jqGrid resizable? I want that sweet little handle in the down right corner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
jQuery('#list').jqGrid('gridResize');
```

(see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid). You should don't forget include jQuery UI and during download of jqGrid include "jQuery UI addons".

Comment: Super excellent! Works like expected! Dunno why I never saw that in the docs... either way I'm happy now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
        var wd = 1000;
        $(grid_selector).setGridWidth(wd);
    }).trigger("resize");
```